# Notice: Undefined index: suppress_filters

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions, homepage, wp-debug

I'm doing some de-bugging on a theme I'm working on and I'm hoping someone can help me please.

I used this function that Justin Tadlock made to display custom post types on the blog page and with wp-debug set to true I get a Notice: Undefined index: suppress_filters message.

The code is as follows:

```
// Custom Post Type for the public blog posts to show on Index or blog page
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

if ( ( is_home() && false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) || is_feed() )
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'news', 'attachment' ) );

return $query;
}
```

If anyone could help that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$query->query_vars['suppress_filters']` is not set you will get that message.

Use `empty($query->query_vars['suppress_filters'])` instead of `false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] )` or use `$query->get('suppress_filters')` like this `false == $query->get('suppress_filters')`.

Untested (minimally tested) but I believe either of those should give you the same results minus the notice.

Comment: Ran into same issue, I used `if ( is_home() && false == $query->get('suppress_filters'))` which works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `$query->query_vars['suppress_filters']` isn't set.  Try this:

```
// Custom Post Type for the public blog posts to show on Index or blog page
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_get_posts' );

function my_get_posts( $query ) {

    if ( 
        ( is_home() && (
            isset( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) && 
            false == $query->query_vars['suppress_filters']  
            )
        ) ||
        is_feed() 
    ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'news', 'attachment' ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I added a check to make sure that `$query->query_vars['suppress_filters']` is actually set before you check to see if it's `false`.  (Also I broke up the `if()` statement for easier reading.  (I think I've matched up all the `(` and `)` correctly.)